# Is it possible to download a file variable in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

Using Coldfusion's `SpreadSheet()` object I have created an excel file and now the user needs to be able to download it.

```
mySS = SpreadsheetNew();
format1 = StructNew();
format1.color="dark_green";
format1.size="24"; 
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(mySS, 7,2,3);
SpreadSheetFormatCell(mySS, format1, 2, 3);
```

essentially I would like something like

```
<cfdownload var="#mySS#">
```

however it's almost never that simple. I realize that I can write the file and then use `cfheader` \ `cfcontent` however I am trying to avoid writing the file if possible.

**Edit**

Based on the suggestion I got from [speshak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103174/speshak) I tried

```
<cfcontent variable="#mySS#"  type="application/msexcel">
```

and the error I got was, am I missing something?

> coldfusion.excel.ExcelInfo is not a supported variable type. The
>   variable is expected to contain binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so thanks to [Raymond Camden's Post](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/7/11/Quick-followup-to-my-CFSpreadSheet-Samples) and speshak here is the final solution.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=filename.xls">
<cfcontent variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(mySS)#"  type="application/msexcel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<cfcontent variable="#mySS#">`

You probably want to set the type attribute as well so the browser knows it's not HTML.