# How can I force a download of a generated Excel file and still save a copy?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a code I based off of this:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetaddrows.html

It currently generates an Excel file, saves it on the server, then offers a link to the excel file.

Here is my current code for **report.cfm**:

```
<cfset todayDate = Now()> 
<cfscript>
       // Get data from a query
       Applicants=QueryExecute("

            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.applicants
            ORDER BY lastname ASC

                               ",[],{datasource="DATABASE"});
       // Create a spreadsheet object with sheetname
       spObj=spreadsheetNew("Applicants",true);
       // Add rows with data from query result. The data start from row 1, col 1. The spreadsheet
       // will have column names.
       spreadsheetAddrows(spObj,Applicants,1,1,true,[""],true);
       dirName=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath());
       // Write spreadsheet to a file
       SpreadsheetWrite(spObj,"#dirName##dateformat(todayDate, "yyyymmdd")#_#TimeFormat(todayDate, "HHmmss")#_Applicants.xlsx",true);
       //SpreadsheetWrite(spObj,"#dirName##DateFormat(todayDate, "yyyymmdd")#_Applicants.xlsx",true);
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
    <a href="#dateformat(todayDate, "yyyymmdd")#_#TimeFormat(todayDate, "HHmmss")#_Applicants.xlsx">Click to download your Excel File</a>
</cfoutput>
```

How can I change it so when a user clicks on the link for **report.cfm** it will not present them *"Click to download your Excel File"* anymore, but automatically trigger the download AND keep a copy of the generated Excel file?

---

Follow-up:

I present a link to the user - "generate last year's report"
This links to report.cfm which, as it is right now, generates the excel file and presents them with the download link.

They do not want that extra click so I'm looking for a solution where the page downloads the file automatically.

With Bernhard's suggestion, I revised my code to this

```
<cfscript>
   - original script -
</cfscript>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#dateformat(todayDate, "yyyymmdd")#_#TimeFormat(todayDate, "HHmmss")#_Year2013GradApps.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel">
```

I am able to force the download, but Excel cannot open the file "because the file format or file extension is not valid."

Comment: You can use the `cfcontent` tag: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html Use `cfheader` tag also to provide content-type

Comment: .. and to clarify, the link and cfcontent/cfheader should be in separate scripts.

Comment: Forget the link altogether.  Replace it with the stuff @BernhardDöbler mentioned.

Comment: You need a link. It just should not be in same script with the cfcontent/cfheader.

Comment: Hi @Leigh, why would  the link be needed when cfheader/cfontent are used?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler -  Not inside the download page, sure :-) .. to *trigger* the download. I could be reading it totally wrong... but the fact that they have placed everything in the same page suggests the OP may be misunderstanding how to structure things. My comment was to emphasize they need two separate pieces here a) Something to *generate* the download dialog ie cfheader/cfcontent and b) something to *trigger* that script when the user performs and action, ie link or a button to be clicked.

Comment: Some follow-up:

I present a link to the user - "generate last year's report"
This links to report.cfm which, as it is right now, generates the excel file and presents them with the download link.

They do not want that extra click so I'm looking for a solution where the page downloads the file automatically.

With Bernhard's suggestion, I revised my code (see follow-up in Question)

Comment: @airpolgas - BTW, if you already know all of this, just disregard my comments. It is not meant to be condescending. I just tend to err on the side of more - rather than less explanation when an asker's background and skill level is unclear ;-)

Comment: Leigh, when you say properly structure, this is what I get from that:

1) keep report.cfm, but remove the link and have it trigger another file (let's call it download.cfm)

2) code download.cfm with what Bernhard suggested, since the file was already built by report.cfm

Is that how I should approach this? (I'll try while waiting for reply)

Comment: @airpolgas - The `<cfcontent>` needs to include the spreadsheet somehow. Either via a file path or in binary form. If you want to use a physical file, use the `file` attribute to specify the full path to the generated file. You can also generate downloads *without* saving anything to a file. See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242817/is-it-possible-to-download-a-file-variable-in-coldfusion/8244517#8244517

Comment: *since the file was already built by report.cfm* No, the file is built inside download.cfm.  See [bare bones download.cfm](http://trycf.com/gist/67a8a3452f0762d41aca5ce27ef5755f/acf2016?theme=monokai). This is what your link would point to.  (Note, example does NOT use physical files as they're allowed on trycf.com).

Comment: @Leigh report.cfm creates a .xlsx file instead of an .xls file. I think that's the reason why I keep getting an error. When I tried your cftry link, I was able to open the file. I changed the extension in the code to xlsx and it gave me the same error when I opened the report.cfm generated files.

Comment: @airpolgas - My bad. Did not notice the spreadsheet was xlsx. That warning is due to a new security feature. You cannot fake out Excel anymore by just changing the extension. It looks at the contents and sees they are not what is expected. For xlsx you have to change the code slightly and the cfcontent mime type. Updated example http://trycf.com/gist/7caf18a24411113f54ea6df0e904b221/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @Leigh I tried the new <cfcontent> but it's downloading filename.xlsx.htm

Comment: @airpolgas - Downloads as filename.xlsx in IE/FF. Which browser?

Comment: I can't run your latest cftry code in IE/C/FF for some reason. I was able to get it to download earlier using Chrome when it was still the .xls code.

Comment: Works fine for me. Sounds like there is something different in your environment. Try starting with a totally new file, call it downloadNew.cfm. Make sure there is no Application.cfm/cfc in the directory that might interfere.  Paste the example into the new file, and open it in your browser, ie `http://yoursite/pathToTheNewScript/downloadNew.cfm` . If it works, the problem is something else.